# Store custom data in Excel AddIn C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, add-in

I created an Excel Addin with C# and Visual Studio 2015. Now I want to store some sheet specific data. Is there a way to store user data in a custom excel object that will serialized by Excel in the xlsx file? I'm not sure how to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use worksheet custom properties to store key/value pairs at worksheet level:

To store:

```
MyExcelSheet.CustomProperties.Add("MyKey", "MyValue");
```

To read and update:

```
foreach (CustomProperty cp in MyExcelSheet.CustomProperties)
{
    if (cp.Name == "MyKey")
    {
        cp.Value = "MyNewValue"
    }
}
```

To delete:

```
foreach (CustomProperty cp in MyExcelSheet.CustomProperties)
{
    if (cp.Name == "MyKey")
    {
        cp.Delete();
    }
}
```

Custom properties are saved in the Excel file, but note that changing them will not mark the workbook as 'dirty'. Therefore, after adding/updating/deleting you should mark the workbook as unsaved:

```
Workbook wb = MyExcelSheet.Parent as Workbook;
wb.Saved = false;
```

Doing this will ensure that the user is prompted to save the workbook if they close it, even if no other changes have been made.

Note that other add-ins and VBA code might also be storing data in custom properties, so you should ensure that you use suitably unique keys.

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197822.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use workbook customXMLPart to store XML data at document level
For example let MyDocumentMetaData be your serializable class:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "myNamespace")]
public class MyDocumentMetaData 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> CellRefrences { get; set; }
    public string ToXML()
    {
        var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("myNamespace", "http://myNamespace.com");
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDocumentMetaData));
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, this, ns);
        var x = stringwriter.ToString();
        return x;

    }

    public static MyDocumentMetaData LoadFromXMLString(string xmlText)
    {
        var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlText);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyDocumentMetaData));
        return serializer.Deserialize(stringReader) as MyDocumentMetaData;
    }
}
```

with this two methods you can read and write your data to excel file:

```
public class CustomXMLPartsRepository 
{
    public MyDocumentMetaData Read()
    {
        var CustomXMLParts = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("myNamespace");
        foreach (CustomXMLPart p in CustomXMLParts)
        {
            return MyDocumentMetaData.LoadFromXMLString(p.XML);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void Write(MyDocumentMetaData data)
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Add(data.ToXML());
    }

    private void clearNamespace(){
        var CustomXMLParts = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.SelectByNamespace("myNamespace");
        foreach (CustomXMLPart p in CustomXMLParts)
        {
            p.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-custom-xml-parts-to-documents-by-using-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2017